# JavaScript how to use (single value) easing functions

Tags: javascript, tween, easing

So I found several implementations of the following type of easing functions:

```
function easeInQuad(t, b, c, d) {
    return c*(t/=d)*t + b;
}
```

but would really like to use the following format instead:

```
function easeInQuad(pos) {
    return Math.pow(pos, 2);
}
```

**How to calculate "pos" ?**

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
They are indeed 2 different functions.
The first expects t: current time, b: beginning value, c: change in value, d: duration
The second expects some calculus to be made beforehand in order to do the same as the first.
I'm trying to find out what are those calculus.

EDIT 2:
I believe I haven't explain my self properly and apologise for that.
Let me put it this way:
How to use the following:
https://github.com/danro/easing-js/blob/master/easing.js

Comment: What's the question? Aren't they two completely different functions?

Comment: *'How to calculate "pos"?'* - You tell us. How does a single `pos` argument relate to what used to be four separate arguments in the first function? Is `pos` supposed to correspond to the `b` argument, or...? The second function can't just pull values out of the air...